# Java trouble finding string

Tags: java, regex

I am having a hard time understanding why this is not working. This is only the portion of the code that is not working.

Username and password are passed to the method as arguments.  I have run test print statements to ensure the values passed are correct as well as that the next line of the file is being assigned correctly

```
fileByteStream = new FileInputStream("credentials.txt");  
inFS = new Scanner(fileByteStream);        


while (inFS.hasNextLine()){                          // If the file has another line
String nextLine = inFS.nextLine();                   // Assign that line to a String

if (nextLine.contains(username)) {                   // Check line for username             
    System.out.println("USERNAME FOUND!");                    

        if (nextLine.contains(password)) {           // Verify password
            System.out.println("PASSWORD FOUND!");
```

Here is my dilemma.  The nextLine.contains(username) is not working as I expected.  It matches an instance anywhere within the line.

I have tried using ("\\b" + username + "\\b") , however, then it does not seem to be finding the username in the line and I cannot figure out why.

If the username is matched, finding the password seems to be working perfectly.

The lines within the text file are formatted as such:

**user.name**             **MD5hashOfPassword**       **"Password"**   **Job**

Comment: `String.contains` does not take a regular expression, it takes a plain string.

Comment: You have double-nested `if` statements which both check the value of `nextLine`, but `nextLine` is not refreshed. Does `nextLine` contain *both* username and password?

Comment: Is there another statement I should research to accomplish searching the document line by line?  Or would you recommend I rethink my whole approach to this altogether?

Comment: As I get it: You are having some input like `john.doe 4334353532 123 Login` and checking for username `123` matches the password.

Comment: Yes, the username and appropriate password are on the same line within the file.  Each line contains new credentials for other persons

Comment: For instance, if the file reads:    john.Doe  21312312 password  admin    As it is now if I pass the arguments: "j" and the correct password, it will work

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some sort of pre-processsing for each line. Extract the parts that you want to match, so you can do an exact check.

Note that I used [`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) for this example, as it works with the example data you provided, but I'm not aware of the actual syntax of the line.

```
String nextLine = inFS.nextLine();
String[] parts = nextLine.split("\\w+"); // '+' allows multiple spaces
String usernameFromLine = parts[0];
String passwordFromLine = parts[2];

if(usernameFromLine.equals(username)) {
    ....
```

Note that this example does not check for boundaries nor does it care for lines with bad syntax. It will crash on both.

Comment: Thanks for pushing me in the right direction on this. I was trying to come up with a way to split the information.  However, **some** of the passwords contain spaces so I could not determine a common factor to split by.   The passwords that have spaces are not needed for my processing (as I am checking against their MD5 hash) and **all** passwords are surrounded by a double quote.  is there a way to split the lines of data while ignoring strings within the double quote?

Comment: As long as some assumptions on the quotes hold (e.g. none in the password) and only the passwords are allowed to include spaces, you could build your own split via consecutive [`String#indexOf(int ch, int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,%20int)).

Comment: Thank you so much. Your response if really appreciated.     On second thought, if the passwords are irrelevant to my programs processing, it does not matter if they get split up.  Sorry, I am new to Java and have been spinning my wheels on this one for a couple days. I really feel like I am making it way more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: So, in terms of pseudocode thought:   for each line > split by whitespace into an array,  test each item of array for username.  If found test for password, etc         sound about right?

Comment: Well you just mentioned that `the passwords are irrelevant` and you want to `test for password` later, which clearly does not fit together. If you're new to java, try to solve this one without code first, e.g. on paper. This will most probably help your final approach in coding it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the passwords in the file are inputted to the program and converted to a MD5 hash.  They are only included in the file so that we can ensure our MD5 is working properly.  Within the program the variable password is the MD5 hash and not the actual 'human language' password from the file.  I wrote it out on paper once, but then upon implementation it did not work.  Back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

You're already using a `Scanner`, which does String tokenisation, but not really using it's power.  Instead of reading the whole line and then doing the work yourself, you can just read the tokens using [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()).  If

```
    while (inFS.hasNextLine()) {                      
        /* Get the username */
        String nextUsername = inFS.next();

        // Is this the username you're looking for?
        if (nextUsername.contains(username)) {
            System.out.println("USERNAME FOUND!");

            /* Consume the next token, even if you're not going to
                do anything with it */
            String nextMD5 = inFS.next();

            // Next token should be the password
            String nextPassword = inFS.next();
            if (nextPassword.contains(password)) {
                System.out.println("PASSWORD FOUND!");
            }
        }

        // ensure you advance to the next line before starting again
        inFS.nextLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help.  This is what ultimately ended up working for me.

```
fileByteStream = new FileInputStream("credentials.txt");  
inFS = new Scanner(fileByteStream);        


while (inFS.hasNextLine()){                                 // If the file has another line
    String nextLine = inFS.nextLine();                      // Assign that line to a String
    String[] lineOfCredentials = nextLine.split("\\s+") 

        if (lineOfCredential[0].equals(username)               // Check first item of array             
            System.out.println("USERNAME FOUND!");                    

                if (lineOfCredentials[1].equals(password)) {             // Verify password
                    System.out.println("PASSWORD FOUND!");
                    fileByteStream.close();
                    return (lineOfCredentials[lineOfCredentials.length - 1);
}
```

Once again, thanks for the help. Really appreciated the feedback.